# consulta sobre getter and setter

Tags: java, poo

El ejercicio es de una sencillez extrema, pero le quiero poner un poco de dificultad y hacerlo con POO. Tengo que pedir 5 numeros y luego hacer una operacion con esos numeros, hay una condicion que los numeros no pueden ser mayores a 10. Ahora bien, en la clase donde declaro los numeros les puse valor1,valor2,valor3,valor4,valor5, la cuestion es que si quiero crear un for para que me pida los numeros uno atras del otro, practica a = new practica(); a.setValor1(leer.nextInt());

como podria hacer para hacer para que verifique la condicion a medida que se van ingresando los numeros, sin tener que poner setValor2, setValor3, etc, ya que el for seria para simplificar el codigo.. Como dije anteriormente, se puede realizar el ejercicio de manera mucho mas simple, declarando solo variables en la misma clase main, pero estoy practicando POO. Aguardo sus comentarios.

Comment: por favor adiciona el código de la clase `Practica` y donde se encuentre el `main`

Comment: Por favor pasa el codigo que tienes del ejercicio.

Comment: No os esforceis, yo se lo he puesto incluso en respuestas que han dado y no hay manera. La gente a veces no está por la labor de cumplir las normas de los sitios.

Comment: Amigos, como ya he mencionado en el comentario anterior, les agradezco mucho a todos pero ya he resuelto la consulta. Para almacenar en un array con un setter se ingresa de esta manera vector.getVariable()[i] = resultado; Era lo que no sabia ya que hace poco estoy trabajando con Poo. Les mando un cordial saludo.

Answer (score -1):

una cosa que podrías hacer es sustituir, en la clase práctica, la declaración de los cinco valores por un array de int de longitud 5. Con eso almacenarías los cinco números en una sola variable.

```
//Creas el array de int
    private int[] numeros;

    public Practica(){
        //lo inicias con longitud cinco
        numeros = new int[5];
    }
```

Y como lo vas a tratar en un for, pues puedes hacer un método getter que te devuelva el array de números o un método al que le pasas la posición y el valor y de este modo te introduce un valor (nextInt()) en una determinada posicion(el valor que toma el iterador en el bucle for).

```
//Devulve el array de int numeros
public int[] getNum(){
        return numeros;
    }

//ingresa en la posicion = posicion del array un número = num
    public void ingresaNum(int posicion, int num){
        numeros[posicion] = num;
    }
```

Ya en el bucle for podrías hacer usar cualquiera de estos dos métodos.

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        Practica practica = new Practica();
        int numero = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
            numero = teclado.nextInt();
            practica.getNum()[i] = numero;
        }
```

O bien,

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    Tarea practica = new Practica();
    int numero = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
        numero = teclado.nextInt();
        practica.ingresaNum(i, numero);
    }
```

Por último, recordarte que si después tienes que operar con ellos, las posiciones de los números en el array empiezan por 0. Por tanto, si quisieras sumar el primer y el tercer valor deberías seleccionar la posición 0 y la 2.

```
//Si lo haces desde el main
int suma = practica.getNum()[0] + practica.getNum[2];

//Si lo haces desde la clase Practica
int suma = numeros[0] + numeros[2];
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola @VerónicacodX. En este sitio no se responden preguntas que no demuestran trabajo ni investigación previa. Lo que comenta el usuario podría ser un ejecicio de clase y aquí no se resuelven ejercicios, se ayuda con las dudas puntuales. Por favor, lee [answer] para ver cuándo y cómo responder. Un saludo.

Comment: Buenas Pablo. Perdona, pero disiento en lo que me comentas. El enlace ya lo leí y no recuerdo nada de que no puedan responderse a trabajos de clase o el usuario tenga que aportar si o si código escrito por él, lo que si recuerdo es que la pregunta debía ser específica. Como bien dice Guille en su pregunta, sabe como hacerlo y quiere mejorarlo y disminuir en código, que más da que sea un trabajo de clase. Se nota que está empezando e informarte sin tener base y sin saber que mirar es un poco duro a veces. Yo le he dicho como hacer algo que el ya sabe con un array y si le interesa los mirará.

Comment: Hola @VerónicacodX. Siento decir que yo también disiento en lo que dices. En la página de [answer] pone claramente "Contesta preguntas bien formuladas" y en una pregunta bien formulada hay que mostrar lo que se ha hecho. Si el usuario dice que ya lo ha hecho de una manera, debería ponerlo para realizar los cambios sobre su trabajo. Se que empezar es duro pero todos hemos empezado alguna vez y aquí si solicita ayuda se le va a dar pero sobre algo concreto. Se ayuda a todo el mundo que muestra algo de interés. Un saludo.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano Sin ánimo de armar debate, y ya lo he planteado antes. Me parece que castigar al que responde, por una pregunta mal hecha o insuficiente es ridículo, más aún si consideramos que se trata de un sitio  de preguntas y respuestas. En todo caso el -1 debería ir a la pregunta y no a la respuesta.

Comment: @Juan, se penaliza el contestar a preguntas mal formuladas o incompletas porque esto no es un foro. Esta página funciona así (o al menos es lo que interpreto al leer las normas y todos los comentarios a preguntas mal hechas). La pregunta, además de voto negativo se ha llevado un reporte que es lo que hay que hacer. Como verás, el comentario que se ha dejado a la pregunta (de otro usuario) se le solicita que añada código que es lo que antes he nombrado.

Comment: Veronica, desde ya te agradezco mucho la colaboracion, me fue de mucha utilidad. Pablo, te pido disculpas, seguramente seas un programador de primera linea y te molesta ver este tipo de preguntas como vos decis "mal formuladas", si las personas la pueden responder es porque tan mal no esta, y si fuera un ejercicio no estaria tratando de que lo solucionen por mi, ya que si tengo que dar un examen no voy a tener a una Veronica al lado para que me ayude. Te prometo para la proxima mejorar mi pregunta asi no me penalizan, gracias por estar tan atento a las preguntas "mal formuladas" Slds

Answer (score -1):

public class Ejemplo{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    practica a = new practica();

    int dato;
    int i = 0;
    // creé esta condición de (i<5) ya que lo que pedías es muy 
    //específico a 5 datos
    while (i < 5) {
        dato = leer.nextInt();
    //en este if se aumenta la variable i 
    //la cual necesita ser 5 o mayor para que el loop termine
    //pero solo se va a incrementar si el dato que damos por teclado
    //es menor o igual a 10, esto para cumplir con la condición que pedías

        if (dato <= 10) {
            a.setValor(dato);
            i++;
        }
    }

}
```

}

**si intentas de agregar mas de 5 números te dará una excepción
ya que tú lo pedías muy específico a 5 números
si quieres ingresar mas datos debes aumentar el tamaño del array o hacerlo de otra manera**

class practica {

```
private int[] array= new int[5];
private int contador = 0; // el objetivo de esta variable es controlar la 
                       //cantidad de números en el array

public void setValor(int a) {
    array[contador] = a;
    contador++;
}
```

}

esta sería mi manera básica de resolver lo que pides

Saludos

Comment: Responder sólo con código se considera de baja calidad, dale editar y explícalo

Comment: lo siento no sabía, acaba de crear la cuenta.